# Чем отличаются логгеры root и django?

Tags: python, django, логирование

В системе логгинга django есть встроенные логгеры **root** и **django**. Как сказано в документации:

> **django**
> The parent logger for messages in the django named logger hierarchy. Django does not post messages using this name.
> Instead, it uses one of the loggers below.

Про **root** четкой формулировки не нашел. Знаю, что *django - это базовый логгер*, а root логирует всё, и против него есть настройка **propogate**. Так в чем же различие?

Comment: Ну, вероятно, root logger это тот который встроен в питон? Правда, в [официальной документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) про него тоже не очень чётко рассказывается